# Azure Function triggered by webhook performs action on compounding list of historical events

Tags: azure, azure-functions, webhooks

A webhook is configured to trigger a JavaScript Azure Function that performs an action. When testing, one webhook event triggers a single execution of the Azure Function, performing the action for that event only. This is the desired behavior.

However, when the Azure Function is activated in the Azure UI, the function executes at set intervals (every 5 minutes, it seems like), performing the action for not only the most recent webhook event but also for all prior webhook events. This behavior repeats even if no event occurred during the last interval. In other words, every 5 minutes the action is performed for all events that ever occurred. This is also true when I test in the UI using the same code I am testing with locally.

I have investigated logs and the associated storage account, monitored the console, and clicked on anything else I can think of, but I cannot find any sort of cache or historical list of events that may be triggering.

**function.json:**

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for any insights.

---

**Edit**

Function code:

```
module.exports = function (context, data) {
    var json = data.body;

    var request = require('request');

    // Parse the webhook event JSON body

    var unparsedEvents = json.events;
    for (let event of unparsedEvents) {
        var ContentId = event.EventData.ContentId;
        var ContentTypeId = event.EventData.ContentTypeId;
        var CommentId = event.EventData.CommentId;
        var options = new Object();

        if (CommentId) {
            options.url = "<url>" + CommentId + ".json";
            options.headers = {
                "Rest-User-Token": "<token>",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            };
        } else {
            options.url = "<url>" + ContentId + "/" + ContentTypeId + ".json";
            options.headers = {
                "Rest-User-Token": "<token>",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            };
        }

        function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(body);

                //For all content types but comments

                var username, profileUrl, subject, url, text;
                if (info.hasOwnProperty('Content')) {

                    username = info.Content.CreatedByUser.Username;
                    profileUrl = info.Content.CreatedByUser.ProfileUrl;
                    subject = info.Content.HtmlName;
                    url = info.Content.Url;
                    text = info.Content.HtmlDescription;
                };

                //For comments

                if (info.hasOwnProperty('Comment')) {

                    username = info.Comment.User.DisplayName;
                    profileUrl = info.Comment.User.ProfileUrl;
                    subject = info.Comment.Content.HtmlName;
                    url = info.Comment.Url;
                    text = info.Comment.Body;
                };
            };

            //Send to Slack

            function sendToSlack(theUsername, theIconEmoji) {

                var theUsername = "Bot";
                var theIconEmoji = ":bot:";

                var payload = {
                    attachments: [{
                        author_name: username,
                        author_link: profileUrl,
                        title: subject,
                        title_link: url,
                        text: text
                    }]
                };
                if (theUsername !== undefined) {
                    payload.username = theUsername;
                }
                if (theIconEmoji !== undefined) {
                    payload.icon_emoji = theIconEmoji;
                }
                var theRequest = {
                    url: urlWebHook,
                    method: "POST",
                    json: payload
                };
                request(theRequest, function (error, response, body) {});
            }

            var urlWebHook = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/<Id>";

            sendToSlack();
        };
    };
    request(options, callback);
};
```

**host.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:01:00",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.<function>": "Debug",
      "default": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "watchDirectories": [
    "Shared"
  ]
}
```

Some error logs:

```
Timeout value of 00:01:00 was exceeded by function
2019-01-09T22:44:10.513 [Debug] Hosting stopping
2019-01-09T22:44:10.514 [Information] Stopping JobHost
2019-01-09T22:44:10.520 [Information] Job host stopped
2019-01-09T22:44:10.520 [Debug] Hosting stopped
2019-01-09T22:44:34.217 [Debug] Workers Directory set to: D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12246\32bit\workers
2019-01-09T22:44:34.411 [Debug] Found worker config: D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12246\32bit\workers\java\worker.config.json
2019-01-09T22:44:34.413 [Debug] Will load worker provider for language: java
2019-01-09T22:44:34.413 [Debug] Found worker config: D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12246\32bit\workers\node\worker.config.json
2019-01-09T22:44:34.414 [Debug] Will load worker provider for language: node
2019-01-09T22:44:34.414 [Debug] Worker path for language worker java: D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12246\32bit\workers\java
2019-01-09T22:44:34.414 [Debug] Worker path for language worker node: D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12246\32bit\workers\node
2019-01-09T22:44:35.070 [Information] Initializing Host.
2019-01-09T22:44:35.071 [Information] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
2019-01-09T22:44:35.073 [Debug] Hosting starting
2019-01-09T22:44:35.103 [Information] Starting JobHost
2019-01-09T22:44:35.111 [Information] Starting Host (HostId=<webhook name>, InstanceId=<id>, Version=2.0.12246.0, ProcessId=11704, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=True, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=~2)
2019-01-09T22:44:35.171 [Information] Loading functions metadata
2019-01-09T22:44:35.319 [Information] 1 functions loaded
2019-01-09T22:44:35.441 [Information] Loading proxies metadata
2019-01-09T22:44:35.443 [Information] Initializing Azure Function proxies
2019-01-09T22:44:36.083 [Information] 0 proxies loaded
2019-01-09T22:44:36.164 [Debug] Adding Function descriptor provider for language node.
2019-01-09T22:44:36.164 [Debug] Creating function descriptors.
2019-01-09T22:44:36.205 [Debug] Function descriptors created.
2019-01-09T22:44:36.206 [Information] Generating 1 job function(s)
2019-01-09T22:44:36.275 [Information] Found the following functions:
Host.Functions.<webhook>
2019-01-09T22:44:36.276 [Information] Host initialized (1164ms)
2019-01-09T22:44:36.284 [Information] Host started (1172ms)
2019-01-09T22:44:36.285 [Information] Job host started
2019-01-09T22:44:36      Error occurred, type: error, text: The process cannot access the file 'D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host\2019-01-09T21-43-54Z-a14e0af183.log' because it is being used by another process., stackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.LogStreamManager.GetChanges(FileSystemEventArgs e) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\LogStreamManager.cs:line 374
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.LogStreamManager.<>c__DisplayClass28_1.<OnChanged>b__0() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\
Diagnostics\LogStreamManager.cs:line 258
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Attempt>b__0() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\OperationManager.cs:line 16
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.Attempt[T](Func`1 action, Int32 retries, Int32 delayBeforeRetry, Func`2 shouldRetry) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\OperationManager.cs:line 42
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.Attempt(Action action, Int32 retries, Int32 delayBeforeRetry) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\OperationManager.cs:line 14
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.LogStreamManager.OnChanged(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\LogStreamManager.cs:line 256
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.LogStreamManager.<>c__DisplayClass27_0`2.<DoSafeAction>b__0(T1 t1, T2 t2) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\LogStreamManager.cs:line 233
2019-01-09T22:44:36.554 [Debug] Debug file watch initialized.
2019-01-09T22:44:36.560 [Debug] Diagnostic file watch initialized.
2019-01-09T22:44:36.562 [Debug] File event source initialized.
2019-01-09T22:44:36.563 [Debug] Hosting started
```

Comment: It will be difficult to determine what's causing your issue without knowing the entire functionapp. Do you have other functions? Are you setting an interval yourself? Are the consumers hitting your webhook every 5 minutes ?

Comment: @jmugz3 Thank you -- I added the Function App code to the question. To answer your questions -- It is the only function in the app. I haven't set an interval. However, the webhook on the source side executes every five minutes and sends the data to the Function App's URL. I suspect the issue is not on the source's side because if I use a Logic App URL instead of a Function App URL to receive the webhook events, the correct events are received.